# Trigger event when product image is changed in admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to trigger when a product image is changed in admin to get the image URL and call my external API to sync the product image from Magento to my operation.

But I don't know how to trigger this. I found an event when the product save button is clicked "product_save_after". But if I use this, even not change the image, it will call my API.

Can you give me some advice!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, this can't be simply done using an event observer.
This needs a customized code based on Jquery that function when image is changed in backend.

Answer (score 0):

A useful Magento Event : **catalog_product_gallery_upload_image_after**
This Event Triggers when we upload the Image in Catalogue Product in Admin
You can use this observer to do some extra work, or call any API or any other Stuff.

I have answered on the Magento Community forum,
Check the detailed answer in the Given Link :

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Trigger-an-API-Call-on-uploading-Images-Magento2/m-p/477530#M13046

[image]

Comment: this is a really useful observer! Just a question: using this observer, is there a way to access to the data of the product that has been saved ? If I call the event data I can only see the image information

Comment: Only Image data will Be there @LouNik, For Product change data you have to use another observer